# Little footprint from HTML5 on Primefaces Client Side Validation (CSV)

Tags: html, primefaces, client-side-validation

I'm trying to use the Client Side Validation (CSV) sample from Primefaces a long time to get the footprint effect of HTML5, but after much searching and multiple attempts I could not get the expected result. I followed all the documentation including putting the necessary parameters in the `web.xml` and the validation itself is working correctly, however the footprint effect could not work.

Added parameter in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

At the top of my document I'm using the notation for HTML 5 document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

- Tried deploy with WildFly 8.2.1 and now WildFly 10.1
- Tried with Primefaces 5.3 and now with 6.1, but no success

My question is how to obtain the little footprint from HTML5 with Primefaces CVS?

Example page: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/csv/basic.xhtml

Comment: What do you mean by _" the little footprint from HTML5 with Primefaces CVS"_? And _"footprint effect"_?

Comment: If you mean the 'little footprint using html5' in the showcase, then then there are two options: CSV works, and it **is** using the 'little footprint using html5' or CSV does not work (and the application just validates server side). There are no other options as far as I know, so please explain what actually is happening.

Comment: The example in showcase show red border only on left and in my code all borders are red.

Comment: That has **nothing** to do with 'little footprint' but just what is defined in the (in this case omega) theme. If you use a different one, that will look different. Try making something invalid in the showcase and then switch the theme to e.g. afterdark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood 'little footprint using html5'. What this means is that it uses html5 capabilities of the browser to be a sort of 'light-weight' implementation in that it does not add loads of code to an element to make client-side validation (CSV) a reality.

So if CSV works, you make use of the 'little footprint' and if CSV does not work at all, then you of course do not have it but that is (hopefully) obvious (the 'little footprint' is not some feature that you can turn on and off)

What you describe in your comment is a pure css/theming thing. The default theme in the showcase is 'omega' which has (as far a I know) the property that fields that are in error do not have a full red boundary but just one on the left. Switching a theme in the showcase after making a field invalid (e.g. to Afterdark) will make this clear.

Comment: You're right, i change ui-state-error to { border-left: 2px solid #ef5350;}. Thank you!